# Extract description from EXIF data and exclude duplicate text

Tags: php, arrays, exif, array-unique

I'm working on an image gallery with portraits where I extract text from Exif data. When I edit the images I am writing the names of the people which I later show in my image gallery as captions.

I would like to make a list, but can't figure out how to make it into an array from which I can exclude duplicates with `array_unique()`.

My code is:

```
$imgdir = 'images/'; //pick your folder ie.: 'images/'
$current_folder = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$allowed_types = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');

$dimg = opendir($imgdir);
while($imgfile = readdir($dimg)){
    if(in_array(strtolower(substr($imgfile,-3)),$allowed_types)){
        $a_img[] = $imgfile;
        sort($a_img);
        reset ($a_img);
    }
}
$totimg = count($a_img);

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Names listing</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for ($x=0; $x < $totimg; $x++){
    if ($x == ($totimg-1))
        $_content = (exif_read_data('images/'.$a_img[$x])[ImageDescription]).'';
    else
        $_content = (exif_read_data('images/'.$a_img[$x])[ImageDescription]).', ';
    $_unique = $_content;
    echo $_unique;
}    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If I have multiple images with the same person I get a list like:

```
John, John, Jane, Jane, Jane, ... etc.
```

What I would like is:

```
John, Jane, ... etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store all of the `ImageDescription` values in a temporary array (e.g. `$descriptions`), then after the loop finishes call `array_unique()` on the temporary array to remove duplicates, then you can optionally alphabetize the values, and finally convert the remaining values to a string using `implode()` with [comma and space] delimiting the values.

```
for($x=0; $x<$totimg; ++$x){
    $descriptions[]=exif_read_data('images/'.$a_img[$x])[ImageDescription];
}
$descriptions=array_unique($descriptions);       // remove duplicates before sorting
sort($descriptions);                             // sort alphabetically
echo implode(', ',$descriptions);                // display csv
```

Comment: I had to add some parentheses, but thank you very much!

Comment: @kdt2017 Yeah, sorry that was sloppy of me.  I've fixed up my code now.  You shouldn't need the extra parenthesis around your `exif` call.  If I am wrong about that, let me know.

Comment: It works fine, thanks. I have also tried to sort the list but with no luck. Is there a simple way to do that?